# Unable to connect to AWS/RDS database instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am attempting to connect to a recently created PostGRES database instance on RDS using SQLWorkbench. When I test the connection it is unable to connect.

I am using the admin username and password. For the SQL Connection Profile I have used this as my URL:

```
jdbc:postgresql://database_instance_name.cdixyzkzrpmy.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/database_name
```

There are no specific details reported from SQLWorkbench other that it was unable to connect after I clicked the test connection button.

Perhaps there are additional settings in the database's RDS access/security settings that need to be set as well to allow for a connection from a non-AWS (local) machine?

Comment: it could be one of a hundred things, you don't give an exact error message or details of the network connection from your SQLWorkbench to AWS.   Voting to close

Comment: Maybe you could instead suggest what I might try to modify in my security group settings to allow for a connection from a local machine? I am starting from scratch, maybe there is a list of items required to allow for this sort of vanilla connection from a local machine?

Comment: In your RDS instance, go to your **VPC security groups** , go to your inbound rules and make sure your port 5432 it is available from your IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by modifying the database's default VPC security group's default inbound rule to allow access to port 5432 from any IP address.